# Webpack SplitChunksPlugin skips numbers in chunk names - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I am using webpack 4.41.2 to pack my project using [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) to only split `lazy()` loaded components.
I have recently noticed a strange **new** behaviour when packing my project. The output files will be named as below - with a gap in sequence numbers. This has never happened before, and my webpack config and version has not changed, but the code has.

```
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 69423ms
Built at: 2020-09-21 11:06:17
                 Asset      Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
           0.bundle.js  20.6 KiB       0  [emitted]
           2.bundle.js  23.5 KiB       2  [emitted]
           3.bundle.js   7.1 KiB       3  [emitted]
           4.bundle.js  7.59 KiB       4  [emitted]
           5.bundle.js  8.34 KiB       5  [emitted]
           6.bundle.js  47.7 KiB       6  [emitted]
        main.bundle.js  1.81 MiB       1  [emitted]        [big]  main
main.bundle.js.LICENSE  3.95 KiB          [emitted]
    main.bundle.js.map  91 bytes       1  [emitted] [dev]         main
              main.css   106 KiB       1  [emitted]               main
          main.css.map   136 KiB       1  [emitted] [dev]         main
```

Notice that the `1.bundle.js` file is missing from the above sequence.

My SplitChunksPlugin is configured as below.

```
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'async',
  minSize: 30000,
  maxSize: 0,
  minChunks: 1,
  maxAsyncRequests: 6,
  maxInitialRequests: 4,
  automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
  automaticNameMaxLength: 30,
  cacheGroups: {
    defaultVendors: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      priority: -10
    },
    default: {
      minChunks: 2,
      priority: -20,
      reuseExistingChunk: true
    }
  }
}
```

My code uses `lazy()` in my `AppRouter` component to split the bundle.

```
import OnePage from '../components/OnePage'
const TwoPage = lazy(() => import('../components/TwoPage'))
const ThreePage = lazy(() => import('../components/ThreePage'))
const FourPage = lazy(() => import('../components/four/FourPage'))
import Test from '../components/four/Test'
...
const FivePage = lazy(() => import('../components/five/FivePage'))
...
```

I have looked inside the bundle.js files and found that

```
3.bundle - contains ThreePage
4.bundle - contains TwoPage
5.bundle - contains FivePage
6.bundle - contains FourPage

0.bundle - contains shared code??
2.bundle - contains shared code??
```

So all code is included, as far as I can see.

Why is `1.bundle.js` not generated by webpack?
Kind regards /K